# C# быстрый поиск с весом результата

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно написать быстрый по нескольким колонкам таблицы одновременно поиск с умной сортировкой (каждый результат должен иметь свой вес, или какой термин тут правильнее?).
Пример: у нас есть таблица Животные с колонками (Вид, Имя).

```
    Животные
    ID  Вид   Имя
    1   кот   Пушок
    2   кот   Котофей
    3   кот   Рекс
    4   пес   Рекс
    5   пес   Пуш
```

Примеры запросов:

```
"Рекс" (Id, вес): `3:1; 4:1.`
"пес Рекс" (Id, вес): `3,1; 4, 2.`
"кот" (Id, вес): `1:1; 2:1; 3:1`
"кот пес" : `1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1`.
"котпес" : `null` (или все результаты, если это не сложно реализовать).
"пес котофей" : `2:1`.
"Рекссссс": `null` (4:1 , если это не сложно реализовать).
"пуш": 1:1, 5:1 (1:0.5, 5:1 , если это не сложно реализовать).
```

Так же важно, чтоб работало все быстро, сопсобы ускорения т.д.

Подскажите куда смотреть и/или быстрый пример, пожалуйста.

**UPD2**. Забыл написать, нужны неполные совпадения (желательно чтоб они были по весу больше, чем полные, но если это вносит трудности - пусть даже неполные совпадения имеют вес как и полные). Обновил список прмиеров выше.

Comment: То есть стандартный алгоритм сортировки вас не устраивает? Нам нужно придумать лучше, чем quicksort?

Comment: @VladD, посмотрите, пожалуйста, примеры, там поможет квиксорт? МНе кажеться, что проблема больше в вычислении веса, чем сортировки.

Comment: @Batanichek, заапдейтил вопрос с вашими примерами. "В вашем случае вес это порядковый номер( в поиске)?" - да.

Comment: @Batanichek, да, но нужно, чтоб еще учитывались и неполные совпадения, к примеру неполные совпадения могут добавлять 0.5 к весу. Регистр не важен.

Comment: @Batanichek, вес влиет на порядковый номер, но не является им. Я не правильно ответил тогда. Полное совпадение по одной колонке добавляет 1 к весу, у "кот котофей" будет 2.

Comment: Посмотрите сюда, может быть это то что ищете? http://selo-blog.blogspot.de/2010/10/sql-ranking.html

Comment: @sss11sdsd: Теперь понятнее. Тогда ответ @Batanichek очень похож на правду.`

Comment: @VladD, да, алгоритмически все правильно, но не юзабельно для больших данных. Я пока сам немного нагуглил, что мне надо: обратный индекс, но решения пока не нашел. Где хранить в РАМ или ФС, реализация и т.д.

Comment: @sss11sdsd: Ну да, для поиска подстрок в таблице вам нужен соответствующий индекс. (Вроде был индекс для полнотекстового поиска, но понятно, что не в любой СУБД.)

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем ответ, но мне кажется это должно помочь вам самостоятельно решить проблему:

0) Пусть изначально у нас есть массив Id,Вес , где вес везде равен 0

1) Разбиваем строку на слова с помощью `String.Split`

2) Для каждого слова, проходим по всему массиву и увеличиваем вес( например)

```
if(str[i]==value){
вес[i]=вес[i]+1
}else if(str[i].Contains(value)){
вес[i]=вес[i]+0.5
}
```

3) Сортируем по убыванию вес и убираем те где вес 0

```
result.where(t=>t.вес>0).OrderByDescending(x => x.вес);
```

На счет скорости не уверен( можно попробовать сделать подсчета веса в [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873962/converting-sql-rank-to-linq-or-alternative). 
И по синтаксису возможно где то не так написал( нет под рукой возможности проверить))

Comment: Решение хорошее, конечно, но в лоб. Производительность да и вообще возможность использования на больших данных - хз.

Comment: На стороне SQL это конечно должно быть быстрее. Можно упростить себе задачу и в C# обрабатывать уже массив в котором есть хотябы одно включение например ка кто [так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996965/query-a-sql-field-for-whether-it-contains-any-one-of-multiple-values)